# Does apache server SSI (Server Side Includes) support arrays and loops?

Tags: apache, server-side-includes

I want to generate an array of key-value-paired items and use a looping mechanism to generate a list of content from them in HTML tags format. Is this possible to do it using apache server SSI?

From what I observed, it seems that it is possible to do it using the w3 jigsaw. But I didn't find anything similar for apache and I must use apache.

this is the way that it can be done using the jigsaw:
https://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/Doc/User/SSI.html#loop

Comment: Have you read through [the Apache SSI documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html)?

Comment: Yep. but there is no loop structure in it